# Google Analytics Ecommerce Tracking capturing prices without tax(magento)

Tags: php, magento, google-analytics

I am working with magento. To work with google analytics, i enabled the GA module in admin side with account id (UA-XXXXXXXX-1), it's working fine. Now for Ecommerce Tracking, it's tracking the price without tax, say example price 15 + tax 1 = 16, it's capturing only the 15 not 16. I am aware of the syntax

```
_addItem(transactionId, sku, name, category, price, quantity)
_addTrans(transactionId, affiliation, total, tax, shipping, city, state, country)
_trackTrans()
```

but in magento i don't know how its working internally. Please guide me..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look @

> /app/code/core/Mage/GoogleAnalytics/Block/Ga.php

```
$result[] = sprintf("_gaq.push(['_addTrans', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s']);",
    $order->getIncrementId(),
    $this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::app()->getStore()->getFrontendName()),
    $order->getBaseGrandTotal(),
    $order->getBaseTaxAmount(),
    $order->getBaseShippingAmount(),
    $this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($address->getCity())),
    $this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($address->getRegion())),
    $this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($address->getCountry()))
);
foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $result[] = sprintf("_gaq.push(['_addItem', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s']);",
        $order->getIncrementId(),
        $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getSku()), $this->jsQuoteEscape($item->getName()),
        null, // there is no "category" defined for the order item
        $item->getBasePrice(), $item->getQtyOrdered()
    );
}
$result[] = "_gaq.push(['_trackTrans']);";
```

Comment: Take a look @ /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/googleanalytics.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can get a product's full price inside a template by using:

```
// $item is the current product.
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());

// Price as number
$priceIncludingTax = $this->helper('tax')->getPrice($product, $product->getFinalPrice());

// Formatted price as currency string
$price = strip_tags($this->helper('checkout')->formatPrice($priceIncludingTax, 2));
```